# Updating column appending a number with column text

Tags: mysql

I want to append number with  my table column text

**Post_sortcode**

```
post-first
post-next
post-next
```

Output

**Post_sortcode**

```
post-first-1
post-next-2
post-next-3
```

Any one help me...

Comment: And do you have a primary key in the table ?

Comment: ya post_id is my primary key

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic variable to get the row number and then update with join something as

```
update Post_sortcode t join
(
  select 
  t1.post_id,
  @r := @r+1 as rr
  from Post_sortcode t1,(select @r:=0)r

)u on u.post_id = t.post_id
set t.post = concat(t.post,'-',u.rr);
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8a44e/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
update tbl_post set post_sortcode=concat(post_sortcode,'-',post_id)
```

Comment: Try this in mysql and see what you get `select 'title-here-'+1 ;`